# Xamarin File Access

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am currently coding a Android Application that changes the Files of an other program with Xamarin & C#. I installed the File Permission Plugin and its working (I also checked it manually in phone settings).
When I click on the button and it should modify the files it just crashes. Don´t know what I am doing...
Would appreciate any reply, since I am new to Xamarin.

Here is my Code I am currently using:

```
            Renegade = new Command(async () =>
            {
                string pak5 = "pakchunk10_s5-Android_ASTCClient.ucas";

                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/Android/data/com.epicgames.fortnite/files/InstalledBundles/FortniteBR/FortniteGame/Content/Paks//" + pak5;

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(pak5, true))
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
                }

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pak5))
                {
                    string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
                }

                Utilities.Convert(Body, Body1, path + pak5, 80782548);
                Utilities.Convert(Mat, Mat1, path + pak5, 8981062);



            });
```

Comment: You can not modify files in another app's sandbox unless your device has root access, typical app file permissions do not grant you root access.

Comment: it IS working without Root Perms. My phone isnt rooted and I had edit access on the file and it is reachable in normal File Explorer

Comment: @FrostOnAcid You want to open .ucas file and modify?

Comment: yes, but i think the fil format isnt important, since it isnt working with any file format. also i dont want to decompress it ;)

Comment: @FrostOnAcid From your path, I see it is external storage, but  the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` is for external storage, maybe it doesn't work for the internal storage.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I think you dont need extra perms for writing internal storage :(

Comment: @FrostOnAcid Now you have solution to do this?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT still no solution :(